How to deal with overlapping data in machine learning
I am creating a Machine Learning Model that determines whether a user is a bot or not, I used seaborn to plot a pairplot and realised most of the data is overlapping. Below is the code I wrote for Standardising, Splitting and Deploying the model. The image is how the model performs with just over 40000 samples. As you can see the model is playing guess work and I'm trying to find out why that is.

X = new_df[['Retweet Count', 'Mention Count', 'Follower Count', 'Tweet', 'Hashtags', 'Verified', 'Created At']]
y = new_df[['Bot Label']].values

y = y.ravel() # Ensuring that y is 1D array instead of a 2D array

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)

Scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = Scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = Scaler.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix


rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 1000)
rfc.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
y_pred = rfc.predict(X_test_scaled)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))



Consider what useful features might be. What is the representation of Location or Created At as a number? Also, is the Hashtags indicator a count of the hashtags, or is it just indicator of a specific hashtag?
If those are indicators of a specific location, time of creation or a specific hashtag, then the model may not be able to distinguish those, as it is not a relevant representation. Dependent on what the columns mean, the same probably holds for Username and Tweet. Think of it in the following way: does a higher value mean something? For counts that's the case, for an indicator of a username it does not.
With all the counts, you can check the distribution, as counts tend to be skewed. In that case consider transformations such as a log transformation.

I used LabelEncoder to change the tweet, username, etc. into numerical values. The bigger problem for me is that the data is just evenly distributed, even when checking the averages amongst count values, the mean hovers around the halfway mark between min values and max values

Using a labelencoder will not be of use for such things. Each tweet will get a separate number that is not of value, as it just identifies that tweet. Each user will either be a bot or not, so having the identifier for that person would either not have any meaning or otherwise, it would just be able to "remember" which user is a bot, meaning that you have leakage from training to testing data. So definitely remove those. Have you done an EDA to see whether the other features are of relevance? For example with plotting.

Next to that, if your mean is so close to halfway, are you sure that the count is done correctly? You didn't use the labelencoder for that, right?

I did not, the LabelEncoder was used for 'categorical data' as the count data was already numeric. Let me try EDA will come back to you
